# Insert Array into an Array of Arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've tried splice, concat, apply, call, etc.

All I am trying to do is take an array like this:

```
[["alksjdflskdj","2","1.33","1.30","", "5","1","1","1","1","1","0","","Other notes"],
 ["test","1","","","","1","0","1","0","0","0","",""],
 ["test3","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
 ["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
 ["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""]]
```

And add something like this inside of the above array:

```
["2018-03-06 04:14:59", "T", "", "", "0"]
```

The end result would look like this:

```
[["alksjdflskdj","2","1.33","1.30","", "5","1","1","1","1","1","0","","Other notes"],
 ["test","1","","","","1","0","1","0","0","0","",""],
 ["test3","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
 ["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
 ["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
 ["2018-03-06 04:14:59", "T", "", "", "0"]]
```

Thanks in advance. This has stumped me.

Comment: `array_of_arrays.push(new_array)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method which adds elements to the end of an array.

```js
var originalArray = [
  ["alksjdflskdj", "2", "1.33", "1.30", "", "5", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "", "Other notes"],
  ["test", "1", "", "", "", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "", ""],
  ["test3", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", ""]
]

var ArrayToPush = ["2018-03-06 04:14:59", "T", "", "", "0"];

originalArray.push(ArrayToPush);
console.log(originalArray)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried and it gave me "thearray.push is not a function"

Comment: @user3259138 i can help you if you can share the code which you have tried

Comment: So this code works, the issue was that I needed to use JSON.parse on the original array, because I was pulling it from local storage. I really appreciate your offer to help @brk

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) as already mentioned by others in order to add a element to an existing array:

```
arr1.push(ele); // arr1 now has ele at last index
```

Either you can make use of [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), which doesn't mutates original `array` and return a brand new one:

```
var arr2 = arr1.concat(ele) // arr1 remains the same and arr2 has arr1 with ele at las index
```

It depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your additional information

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to achieve your goal. Here's a snippet:

```
var initial = [
    ["alksjdflskdj","2","1.33","1.30","", "5","1","1","1","1","1","0","","Other notes"],
    ["test","1","","","","1","0","1","0","0","0","",""],
    ["test3","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
    ["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],
    ["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""]
];

var new_array = ["2018-03-06 04:14:59", "T", "", "", "0"];
initial.push(new_array);
```

`initial` now contains the new array of arrays you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#push()` to add a new element to an array.

```js
var data = [["alksjdflskdj","2","1.33","1.30","", "5","1","1","1","1","1","0","","Other notes"],["test","1","","","","1","0","1","0","0","0","",""],["test3","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""]],
    arr = ["2018-03-06 04:14:59", "T", "", "", "0"];
data.push(arr);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Array.push()` like this

```
var datas = [["alksjdflskdj","2","1.33","1.30","", "5","1","1","1","1","1","0","","Other notes"],["test","1","","","","1","0","1","0","0","0","",""],["test3","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""],["","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","",""]];
```

then

```
datas.push(["2018-03-06 04:14:59", "T", "", "", "0"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the elements you want to push in a variable

the use `push()`

```
arr.push(ele);
```

this will automatically increase the index and inserts it in the last

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer.